# subversion with turtoisesvn, visualsvn manager, eclipse and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to setup Apache Subversion on my PC, but I'm not sure about the workflow.

I've created a repository in the VisualSVN Server Manager console. I've created a project structure within that repository, where a folder called `MyProject` has three folders called `/trunk`, `/tags` and `/branches`.

Then I created a folder on my disk called `MyRepos`. Within that folder I created another folder called `Java_Projects`. Into that folder I checked out `MyProject` folder. This is my working copy, right?

Now I created a maven project inside the trunk (in the working copy folder where I checked out to) and the trunk and converted it into an Eclipse project, so the trunk now contains the src and target folder, the pom as well as the .project and .classpath files.

Then I imported this project as "existing project" into the Eclipse workspace.

I then wanted to delete the two java-files automatically created my maven. It wouldnt let me do that in eclipse. So I deleted them directly from my disk, from the trunk folder.

Then I created two new classes in eclipse and commited the whole project from within eclipse. But the two files I created in Eclipse are neither visible in the VisualSVN Server Manager console nor in my local copy. I've tried commiting in Eclipse and updating in the trunk folder several times, but the files dont show up.

What am I doing wrong? How do I, after having created a project-structure in the repository (which in my case is controlled by the VisualSVN Server), create a new maven project and work with that?

Comment: you mean the two classes you created disappeared after committing ?

Comment: no, the classes I created are only visible in Eclipse. When I commit them via Eclipse, they dont appear anywhere else. Neither in the repository nor in the visual svn manager

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Comment: Sorry, lost track of it :)

Comment: @user3813234 Thank you! :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you used `svn checkout` to get MyProject from the repository, then 'Yes' you have a working copy of this directory,
2. Use `svn st -v` to analyze status if items your working copy. I guess that you've performed some file operations without using svn client thus you will see missing and unversioned items there. You have to perform copy / move / delete / rename operations using svn client only. Otherwise you can get missing / unversioned items in your working copy.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html).